# Cannot find interface declaration and Attempting to use forward class errors

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Ok so my Xcode randomly decided to be funky..

I have a class called TVBrowseCategoryViewController, here is the .h:

```
#import "TVBrowseCategoryCell.h"
#import "TVNativeFeedViewController.h"

@interface TVBrowseCategoryViewController : TVNativeFeedViewController

@end
```

At first, the @interface line gives me a warning, "Class TVBrowseCategoryViewController defined without specifying a base class", but then when I build the project I get these 2 errors for the same line:

> Cannot find interface declaration for 'TVNativeFeedViewController',
>   superclass of 'TVBrowseCategoryViewController'; did you mean
>   'TVMainViewController'?
>
> Attempting to use the forward class 'TVMainViewController' as
>   superclass of 'TVBrowseCategoryViewController'

I've tried cleaning Xcode, cleaning the build folder, deleting derived data, restarting Xcode, checking for circular imports(pretty sure there are none) but nothing is working.

Comment: Can you add the code for the file "TVNativeFeedViewController"?

Comment: There's a lot of code..do you want to see just the header and the imports?

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say the .h file.  The error says it can't find the @interface for that class.  I want to see why it's not finding it.

Comment: Just the header to start with might be useful.

Comment: Here is TVNativeFeedViewController.h http://pastebin.com/5YkK6g9Z

Comment: Can't say I see a problem.  There is something amiss with that file.  The error is saying that it doesn't know what the superclass you are inheriting from is.  Start trying things to get it to find the @interface (probably a simple error).

Comment: Weird..because I have other classes that are inheriting from TVNativeFeedViewController as well and there's no errors there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so I was wrong, the problem was that I actually did have circular imports.

Comment: Hello @thisiscrazy4 please explain your solution. i am fatch same issue

Comment: Please explain solution please. I have same issue